# TCL:How to list all files in a directory and create a radiobutton for each item

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing a piece of code to list all items in a directory and then create a radiobutton for each of these items.
I am not able to achieve this with the below code:

```
proc check_lib_name {} {
    global ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename
    cd $ENTRYfilename/$ENTRYfilename5
    set dirnames [glob -type d *]
    foreach f $dirnames {
        radiobutton .top.d.$dirnames -text $dirnames -variable list_libs
        grid .top.d.$dirnames -sticky nsew
        puts $ENTRYfilename5
    }
}
```

Only 1 radiobutton is getting created with all names appended into it.
Also, I am a bit confused how to give a different column and row values to each radiobutton.

Comment: Why are you using `$dirnames` instead of `$f` in the loop? Also, not all characters are allowed in window names, you might need to sanitize the filename into a valid window name first.

Comment: Thanks Jerry,
I changed the code a bit, but its still having single radio button.

proc check_lib_name {} {
global ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename
##cd $ENTRYfilename/$ENTRYfilename5
cd $ENTRYfilename
set dirnames [glob -type d *]
puts $dirnames
foreach f $dirnames {
set b 7
set r 1
radiobutton .top.d.$f -text $f -variable list_libs
grid .top.d.$f -row $b -column $r -sticky nsew
incr b
puts $ENTRYfilename5
}
}

Comment: `set b` should be outside the loop. Otherwise it will be equal to 7 every time before you use `radiobutton`

Comment: That helps.. now i have all buttons in place

Comment: @danish, please add an answer with the working code. If you do that, this question might have some value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me. Hence adding it for future reference for others.

```
proc check_lib_name {} {
    global ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename f
    ##cd $ENTRYfilename/$ENTRYfilename5
    cd $ENTRYfilename
    set dirnames [glob -type d *]
    ##puts $dirnames
    set b 7
    foreach f $dirnames {
        set r 2
        puts $f
        radiobutton .top.d.$f -text $f -command $f.list -value $f.abc
        grid .top.d.$f -row $b -column $r -sticky nsew
    }
}
```